# React Component, with a nested component access this.props

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I am stuck with a small challenge, and that is the how to have a sub-component access things like this.props (specifically looking for this.props.history). My code is essentially;

```js
// app.js, setup a router...
return (
  <Router>
    <Route path="/componenta" component={ComponentA}/>
  </Router>
);
```

```js
// Component A has access to this.props
class ComponentA extends Component {
  componentDidMount() {
    console.log('The props are ', this.props);
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
         <h1>Hello from Component A</h1>
         <ComponentB/>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

```js
// ComponentB does not have access to this.props, 
// and I know it is because it is a sub-component here.
class ComponentB extends Component {
  componentDidMount() {
    console.log('The props are ', this.props);
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <h1>Hello from Component B</h1>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

I feel like it is something simple I am missing, any suggestions?

Thanks.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions and comments. I wanted to refrain from passing anything in as I wanted the component to be entirely independent. But, it makes sense that the router is passing these properties into the routed component.

I see my 2 options as passing in the necessary props, or utilize a state engine such as redux and put the necessary data into the store.

Comment: If you have the ability to convert your components to be functional instead of classes, you could use the [`useHistory` hook](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/Hooks/usehistory). Then you wouldn't have to pass any props.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

React router automatically passes `ComponentA` props that belong to react router. That's why you see them in `ComponentA`. It will provide `match`, `location`, and `history` ([docs](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/Route/route-props)).

You can think of `Route` as being something like this:

```js
class Route extends React.Component {
  render() {
    if (props.path == *actual_url*) {
      return React.createElement(props.component, {history, match, location});
      // Which in your case results in
      // <ComponentA history={history} location={location} match={match} />
    } else {
      return null;
    }
  }
}
```

*Note: This is a very simplified illustration. Actual Route class is [here](https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/blob/08662e0d164d00335f071539c68e1483fb04a13c/packages/react-router/modules/Route.js#L30) and is a little more complicated.*

So you have to manage those props from there. To access them in children components, you will need to pass the props you want explicitly like this:

```js
<ComponentB 
  history={this.props.history} 
  location={this.props.location} // If needed
  match={this.props.match} // If needed
/>
```

Or if you know you want to pass all props to the nested component, you could use this shorthand:

```
<ComponentB {...this.props} /> // will result in same props as above example
```

Personally I prefer to be explicit and use the first example, as just doing `{...this.props}` tends to lead to components receiving way more props than they need. But that much is up to you.

Comment: I too like to be explicit especially because there are ways to optimize components to prevent unnecessary rerenders but if you pass in unused properties it may prevent those efforts by redundant renders.

Comment: Yeah, I pretty much never use that method in practice Mostly because things change, and even though at the time the component may need all of the parent's props, it may not in the future. Plus I think it improves readability. But it is a valid option, so I listed it.

Comment: You're welcome, check out my comment about using react router hooks. They would accomplish what you're looking for.

Answer (score 1):

Change your line where you use ComponentB to include history if you want to use it inside ComponentB:

```
<ComponentB history={this.props.history} />
```

Answer (score 1):

You're failing to pass props from `ComponentA` to `ComponentB`.

```
return (
  <div>
    <h1>Hello from Component A</h1>
    <ComponentB passedProps={this.props} />
  </div>
);
```

Comment: The one thing to note if you do this is that inside ComponentB you'll have to reference say `history` by using this.props.passedProps.history.

Comment: A more effective way of passing all props to a child would be `<CompB {...this.props} />` this way they won't be nested in `passedProps`.

Comment: well of course, but we aren't focused on what things are named or in what way it's referenced. The question is asking how do I provide access to props from component A in B

Comment: Yes Brian, that is an effective way to pass all props to ComponentB but that's not always desirable so I stuck to only passing the one property referenced in the question (i.e. history).

Answer (score 1):

welcome to SO, i see that you are not passing any `prop` to the `ComponentB` so you have to do something like this;

```
<ComponentB history={this.props.history}/>
```

And then you will be able to use the `history` on your `ComponentB`

Comment: I don't like that, as I would prefer the component was independent and not rely on inputs, ideally. Although ,that seems to be a requirement given the other comments.

Comment: In that case you can use the `Context` api, but you will need a lot of code to configure this. [docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html)

Comment: I was looking at Context, but felt it was a bit heavy for what I was attempting to accomplish. I have a strong desire to have components be as self-sufficient as possible.

Comment: Yes it looks like `Context` is too much for your example, at any case you can will need to pass the props to the `Components`, this is how react is designed. there are other ways to get the history from your `Router` but this is the easiest and more straightforward way